# Jquery datatables does not work with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables plugin, but the pagination does not work. I have instantiating CSS and JS requirement, but I don't know why this does not work.

Everything works, just pagination buttons not, any suggestions?

HEAD:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"></style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.vertical-tabs.min.css"></style>

FOOTER:

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/action/controller.js"></script><!-- this my js -->

HTML:

    <table id="datagrid_test" class="datagrid">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>FIELD1</th>
        <th>FIELD2</th>
        <th>FIELD3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
        for ($i=0; $i < 20 ; $i++) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa<?=$i?></td>
        <td>bbb<?=$i?></td>
        <td>ccc<?=$i?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php  } ?>
    </tr>
    </table>

JS: 

$(document).ready( function(){    
     $('#datagrid_test').dataTable();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the cause of problem is the mismatch of library versions: you have datatables 1.10.2 and you use script of bootstrap integration for version 1.10.12, so just include a proper version of datatables to fix the issue.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

One more thing, it looks like you have one redundant closing tr tag just before closing table tag.

Comment: Thank you  @ConstantineUA. This is Work fine!